# Multi-step AJAX form in WordPress

Tags: php, forms, wordpress, jquery

I'm building a multi-question AJAX form where the first question appears and the second is hidden and depends on the answer to the first.

My jQuery listens for the click and stores the variables and then hides the original HTML and shows the second div. This is regardless of the answer to the first.

How can I a) provide an IF response on the show/hide jQuery based on the value of the first variable and b) not rely on hiding a specific div id and showing a specific div id if I have something like 50 questions in 50 divs!?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: @sczizzo partly guilty although I'm more open to a discussion rather than an answer. I mean honestly, the one approach I know is to show/hide an html element. So, aside from retrieving information from the database, I'm just wondering if there's an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: http://wpquestions.com/question/show/id/1484

Specifically, he points to the **cformsII** plugin (http://www.deliciousdays.com/cforms-plugin/)